# Ubuntu - Can't install software-properties-common

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation

I am trying to install `software-properties-common`, but I am getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
software-properties-common : Depends: python-gi but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I actually tried to install this `python-gi` dependency, but getting again an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-gi : Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.29.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 (>= 1.31.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Ubuntu version**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

**EDIT**
Result of `apt-cache policy software-properties-common python3-gi python-gi`

```
software-properties-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.82.7.7
  Version table:
     0.82.7.7 0
        500 http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     0.82.7.5 0
        500 http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     0.82.7 0
        500 http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
python3-gi:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.2.2-1~precise
  Version table:
     3.2.2-1~precise 0
        500 http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.0-3 0
        500 http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
python-gi:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.2.2-1~precise
  Version table:
     3.2.2-1~precise 0
        500 http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.2.0-3 0
        500 http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You seem to have issues beyond just this as in 14.04 Ubuntu the dep is `python3-gi`, not python-gi. Maybe add - What flavor of 14.04 & the results of `apt-cache policy software-properties-common python3-gi python-gi`

Comment: @doug question edited

Comment: you tagged this question as 14.04 but I guess you're using 12.04? If that's the case no clue as to what you've done as python-gi, libglib2.0-0, gir1.2-glib-2.0 are all part of the default install & not easily removed

Comment: Nop @doug, I am really using `14.04 LTS`.

Comment: Well, the 14.04 version of `software-properties-common` does depend on `python3-gi`, as @doug said. Apparently you tried to install some other version of `software-properties-common`. Where did you get it? You need to tell the whole story for a chance to get help.

Comment: run this, copy & either add to post here or in a pastebin & post link ( https://paste.ubuntu.com/ )  `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`